# Most effective way to re-evaluate useState when its initial value changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Say I have a useState like so:

```
 const [carouselContents, setCarouselContents] = useState(store.getCarouselContents());
```

I do this because I need the setter in some places. However, the result of course is that `carouselContents` always renders with the initial value of `store.getCarouselContents()` unless I call the setter.

What is the best way to force the component to re-evaluate the value of `carouselContents` on render? Is there any way without doing this?

```
if (store.getCarouselContents() !== carouselContents) {
   setCarouselContents(store.getCarouselContents());
}
```

To head off the inevitable question, I don't set state on the store from within the frontend code - it is only updated by push messages from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to get the carouselContents as a prop, then, make the change with the useEffect.
Something like this:

```
// OPTION 2
function Question14_2({ carouselContentFromParent }) {
  const [carouselContents, setCarouselContents] = useState(carouselContentFromParent);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("carousel has changed");
    setCarouselContents(carouselContentFromParent);
  }, [carouselContentFromParent]);
  return (
    <div>{carouselContents}</div>
  );
}

function Question14_2_wrapper() {
  const carouselContent = store.getCarouselContents();
  return ( <Question14_2 carouselContentFromParent={carouselContent}  /> );
}
export default Question14_2_wrapper;
```

Without redux or another store provider, I don't have any better idea.